# PHP in array equal/not equal

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, conditional-statements

Im working on wordpress website and i have problems with arrays.

Here is code:

```
'text' => array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'title' => __('Subtitle', 'wpml'),
    'description' => __('Enter subtitle text or leave empty to hide.', 'wpml'),
    'condition' => array('type', '==', 'something1')
),
```

How can I put multiple items into `condition`?

I need 3 items (something1,something5,something8) to be equal to the condition.

Edit:
This is part of plugin in the backend, i have options for the elements where is allowed to enter description and where is not.

Here is full class:

```
function shortcode_options_fields() {

        $this->shortcode_options = array(
                'type' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'title' => __('Type', 'wpml'),
                'description' => __('Select services type.', 'wpml'),
                'options' => array(
                    'service1' => __('Service 1', 'wpml'),
                    'service2' => __('Service 2', 'wpml'),
                    'service3' => __('Service 3', 'wpml'),
                    'service4' => __('Service 4', 'wpml'),
                    'service5' => __('Service 5', 'wpml'),
                    'service6' => __('Service 6', 'wpml'),
                    'service7' => __('Service 7', 'wpml'),
                    'service8' => __('Service 8', 'wpml'),
                    'service9' => __('Service 9', 'wpml'),

                ),
                'default' => 'service1'
            ),
            'text' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'title' => __('Title', 'wpml'),
                'description' => __('Service title.', 'wpml')
            ),
            'subtitle' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'title' => __('Subtitle', 'wpml'),
                'description' => __('Enter subtitle text or leave empty to hide.', 'wpml'),
                'condition' => array()
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'title' => __('Description', 'wpml'),
                'description' => __('Service description.', 'wpml'),
                'condition' => array('type', '==', 'service1')
            ),

        );
    }
```

Only service 1,5 and 8 shuld have description nothing else.

I hope this will make more clear,
Thanks

Comment: Is this part of a plugin or wordpress core ?

Comment: More information, code - where is that passed to show us or tell us

Comment: what is this "something1" meta key?? or any custom field ?? and are you applying this in wp-query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details on the documentation for Wordpres:
https://codex.wordpress.org/

But I believe you are looking for something like:

```
'text' => array(
'type' => 'text',
'title' => __('Subtitle', 'wpml'),
'description' => __('Enter subtitle text or leave empty to hide.', 'wpml'),
'condition' => array('type', '==', ('something1', 'something2', 'something3'))
),
```

Comment: Did you forgot the : `array( ... )` or is that something I don't understand.